# Maven Release Plugin with JAXB issues

Tags: java, maven-2, jaxb, xjc, maven-release-plugin

We've got a project set up to use the Maven Release Plugin which includes a phase that unpacks a JAR of XML schemas pulled from Artifactory and a phase that generates XJC classes. We're on maven release 2.2.1.

Unfortunately the latter phase is executing before the former which means that it isn't generating the XJC classes for the schema. A partial POM.XML looks like:

```
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <!-- phase>generate-sources</phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>ourgroupid</groupId>
              <artifactId>ourschemas</artifactId>
              <version>5.1</version>
              <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/xsd</outputDirectory>
              <excludes>META-INF/</excludes>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-buildnumber-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <doCheck>true</doCheck>
        <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.xsd</include>
            <include>*/*.xsd</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <!-- args>
            <arg>-Djavax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema=org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory</arg>
        </args-->
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I've tried googling for it, unfortunately I ended up with a case of thousands of links none of which were actually relevant so I'd be very grateful if someone knew how to configure the order of the release plugin steps to ensure a was fully executed before it did b.

Thanks

Comment: which maven version are you using? because there were bugs in the lifecycle execution order before 2.2.0, I think

Comment: 2.2.1 unfortunately, at least unfortunate in that otherwise upgrading would've been an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some issues with ordering of execution (e.g. [MNG-3719](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3719), [MNG-2258](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2258)) but it should be fine with Maven 2.2.1 and *plugins should be executed in the same order as they are listed in the POM when bound to the same phase*. And indeed, with your POM slightly modified:

- I uncommented the `<phase>generate-sources</phase>` of the dependency plugin
- I added `id` to the `execution` elements
- I used a "fake" dependency for the dependency plugin

I get the following output:

```
$ mvn generate-sources 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Q3070794
[INFO]    task-segment: [generate-sources]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [dependency:unpack {execution: step1-unpack}]
[INFO] Configured Artifact: c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2:jar
[INFO] Unpacking /home/pascal/.m2/repository/c3p0/c3p0/0.9.1.2/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jarto
 /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3070794/src/main/webapp/xsd
with Includes null and excludes:META-INF/
[INFO] [dependency:copy {execution: step1-unpack}]
[INFO] Configured Artifact: c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2:jar
[INFO] Copying c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar to /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/Q3070794/src/main/webapp/xsd/c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
[INFO] [jaxb2:generate {execution: step2-xjc}]
[INFO] Started execution.
...
```

The `dependency:unpack` and `dependency:copy` is done **BEFORE** `jaxb2:generate`. Unless I'm missing something, this is the expected result. Tested with Maven 2.2.1.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I think perhaps the middle step having a phase was causing it to execute the jaxb2 early rather than sequentially for the three phases listed.